# Timer Issue in Bot Application: i want to send msg (async method) when user ideal for 10mins(timer reaches the interval 10mins)

Tags: c#, timer, bots, botframework

I want to post message on conversation like "`Do you want to know anything? (Yes or No)"` when user was idle for 10 mins.

```
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)

{

Timer aTimer = new Timer(15000);

aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

aTimer.Stop();

aTimer.Enabled = false;

aTimer.AutoReset = false;

aTimer.Start();

aTimer.Enabled = true;
**}**

public async Task OnTimedEvent(Activity activity)
**{**
Activity reply;

reply = activity.CreateReply($"{activity.Text}");

await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

}
```

I tried the above, but after publish bot is not responding even it's not initiating first message.

Please help me how to trigger event or method. please do it workable.

Comment: Plz help me on this timer issue